# Self containing war with embeded jetty

Tags: war, lift, embedded-jetty

I have a sbt project in scala and I am starting embed jetty with 
**java mywar.war package.main**.

I am following jetty documentation and my main class looks like:

```
object RunWebApp extends App {
    val server = new Server
    val scc = new SelectChannelConnector
    scc.setPort(8080)
    server.setConnectors(Array(scc))

    val context = new WebAppContext()
    context.setServer(server)
    context.setContextPath("/")
    context.setWar("src/main/webapp") //works in IDEA
    //also tried this: 
    //val warUrl=RunWebApp.getClass.getClassLoader().getResource("/mywar.war")
    //              warUrl.toExternalForm() do not work!
    context.setWar("/mywar.war") // do not work!

    server.addHandler(context)

    try {
        println(">>> STARTING EMBEDDED JETTY SERVER, PRESS ANY KEY TO STOP")
        server.start()
        while (System.in.available() == 0) {
            Thread.sleep(5000)
        }
    server.stop()
    server.join()
    } catch {
        case exc : Exception => {
          exc.printStackTrace()
          System.exit(100)
        }
    }
}
```

But the browser on localhost:8080 renders Directory / and not a web app. What to do?

Comment: It doesn't seem a sbt question. If you used maven to manage the build, would you use [tag:maven] tag?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using these two files to get jetty running:

https://github.com/vn971/roboCup/blob/master/src/main/scala/bootstrap/liftweb/Start.scala

https://github.com/vn971/roboCup/blob/master/build.sbt

The first one is Scala code to make jetty start. The `val webappDir` shows a hacky technique to start the server in "assembled" mode (*.war or *.jar).

The second is the build file. Everything inside is optional and may be skipped. But:

- I use `sbt-revolver` for a fast edit-compile-see cycle, and to totally prevent memory/resource leaks.
- I use `sbt-assembly` plugin to package *.war / *.jar
- Lines around "`resourceGenerators in Compile`" show how make `sbt-assembly` copy /src/main/webapp into *.war / *.jar.
- I use `jetty-webapp` dependency in the main scope, not "provided". This is because don't want to use any tomcats/glassfishes at all. The application is startable with `java -jar appname.jar`.

I think that's all. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Your method seems better then mine but the result is the same unfortunately. I have installed sbt assembly and I am generating a .jar containing the webapp and my main class is setting context.setWar(context.getClass.getClassLoader().getResource("webapp").toExternalForm()) but when i browse localhost:8080 I see all the files containined in the jar but is NOT loaded as web app ( i mean with and index.html that uses the css etc but it looks like a repository instead)

Comment: It's probably an issue of your exact application, then. A missing web.xml or something like that.